# is my Corsair CS450M PSU bad?

Tags: power-supply

My computer won't turn on. MB is Gigabyte GA-F2A88X-D3HP, CPU is AMD FM2+ socket 4-core, RAM is 4 Gb Kingston. There are no diagnostic beeps, the CPU seems to be cold, the LED lights flashing numbers does not light up. Suspecting the PSU (Corsair 450 watt) I removed its harness from MB and tested voltage between green (ground) wire and the the other leads. All showed 4.34 volts except the blue-purple lead which showed 0.75 volts. Shouldn't there be readings of 12v, 5v and 3.3v as in diagrams I found on the Internet?

Comment: Can you jump-start the PSU with a paperclip between pins 4 & 5 (ensure correct orientation)? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ea1dcJ0QyAE

Answer (score 0):

Diagnosing PSU fails at consumer-level is an almost impossible task, even with a multi-meter.

1. It's very difficult at consumer level to measure voltage from a PSU, because you cannot simulate the loads.
   As an example - with a multimeter & no load, a rail seems to be pushing the perfect 12v - yet once you add the load, it turns out it can only push 9v, & things start to get flakey. Some multimeters can simulate load - which is great… if you know what the load ought to be, otherwise it's useless.
2. It won't lift to full voltage on all the rails until it powers up, & then you're back to 1.

*Tale of woeful implementation of the above…*
I spent 15 years as an electronics maintenance engineer, in the field with no test bench, just a multimeter. I spent 15 years asking for the company to produce simple 3-colour LED load testers so we could check PSUs in situ. Never happened, so for 15 years the way to test a PSU was to swap it out & see if the new one worked better:\

Comment: Thank you Tetsujin for explaining why multi-tester is useless for diagnosing defective PSU. Here's another question: is 7 year old MB more likely to fail than same vintage PSU? I am assuming CPU is not the problem.

Comment: Even if it was 'more likely' the statistic won't tell you which actually failed ;) PSUs do  tend to get 'tired' over time rather than catastrophically fail - hence my work request for a decent tester :\ Many pro facilities still use the 'swap it out & see if it gets better' approach. Sometimes it's just quicker & easier - nice if you have a shop full of spares, not so easy at consumer level though.;) To further explain 1. in my answer - without loading, the rail can say a perfect 12v… but under correct load you discover it's only pushing 9v & that's why things get flakey.

Comment: If the PSU tested with multi-meter WITHOUT A LOAD reads 4.34v on all leads, wouldn't that indicate a failed PSU. Wouldn't it show 12v, 5v and 3.3v BECAUSE it wasn't under load?

Comment: Not necessarily. Without a pinout diagram it would be hard to say for sure, but if the PSU isn't kicked into 'live' mode, it might just trickle [or even leak, some of them are better specced than others, of course ;) It has to have sufficient power going to the mobo to 'know' how to start up when asked.

Comment: Thank you for this info. So you're saying the ONLY way to test the MB and the old PSU is with a known-to-be functioning (new) PSU plugged into the MB, right?

Comment: It's not the *only* way, but it's the only way if all you have is a multimeter.